# Barplot label mismatch

Tags: r, bar-chart, axis-labels

I want to add a rotating 45-degree x-label on my barplot, so I draw a label-free barplot and use `text` function to add those labels. However, I found my labels did not locate exactly on the center of each bar as I set in the `x` parameter (from 1 to 10). Why this happened and how to solve it? Thanks for any suggestion first.

[barplot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7y43.png)

My code:

```
barplot(10:1)
text(x = 1:10, y = par("usr")[3] - 0.45,
     labels = LETTERS[1:10],
     xpd = NA, srt = 45, cex = 1, adj = 1)

## srt is for rotating labels
```

Comment: `b <- barplot(10:1); text(x = b, etc)`. The return value of `barplot` are the x axis positions as a matrix.